# php creates folder with 341 permissions

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, mkdir

Didn't got any luck finding an answer on google , so this is my last try before trying other methods.

I have a script like this:

```
        // get current year and month
        $cur_year = date('Y');
        $cur_month = date('m');
        $long_type = $this->getFile_longtype();

        $folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".FOLDER_CMS."/uploads/$long_type/$cur_year/$cur_month";

        // check whether the folder exists
        if(!is_dir($folder)){

            // try to make the folder recursively
            if(!mkdir($folder,"0777",true)){

                logError($message, __FILE__, __LINE__);
                throw new Exception("Failure creating proper directories");

            }

        }
```

to make it work , I chmod'ed the uploads directory and all it's files and dirs to 777 ( beter suggestion here? )

The long type evaluates to 'images' and this is a directory has already been created on the server.

Now , the script create the folder named with year with the permissions 341. This not wat I want because it terminates the recursive folder buildup or blocks it's content from me.

Any help or suggestions?

**php version** : 5.2.5

**configure command** : './configure' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mhash=/opt/mhash/' '--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-ttf' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the string "0777", use 0777.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Alex, you suppose to enter OCTAL value not a STRING also, for security reasons **never** give full permission to folders use **0755** instead.

Comment: what permission should I give the files that I will store in those folders?

Answer (score 0):

The real permissions depend on the parameter to mkdir and the [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/1/umask). The umask is subtracted from the permissions given to mkdir. Try setting your umask to 0 before doing the mkdir.

Comment: this did not changes anything except that the permissions changed from 341 tot 441 or something like that.

Comment: Setting umask to 0 didn't resolve this issue for me either. The issue was mkdir was trying to set great permissions on the child than the parent folder

Answer (score 0):

I have also just encountered this issue where PHP sets the permissions to `1314`, despite `mkdir` being set to `0755`. This issue was that the folders that were being created were under a parent folder with the permissions `0700`. When I changed the permissions with `mkdir` to `0700` it created the folders with the correct permissions. So it seems (quite logically) you cannot permission a child folder with greater permissions than it's parent.

In your case, a parent folder was probably set to `0755` and you were attempting to create a child with `0777`.